# Edit cells between two cells with specific text in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to fill cells with colour (colour does not matter, as it just needs to look like a block) in a row using a VBA macro.  I want it to be a macro as the START and END cells will change weekly.  I haven't included it, but the topmost row contains days of the week and hours of the day, in 4-hour blocks.

I have six rows in total and each one contains the word "START" in one cell, and "END" in one cell.  They are spaced randomly from one another, and all other cells contain "0".

So something like this:

0 0 0 0 START 0 0 0 END 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 START 0 0 0 0 END 0 0 
0 0 START 0 END 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 START 0 0 0 0 0 0 END 0 0 0 0

Where I want the cells in between "START" and "END" to be filled in either by:

a) A Macro that can colour in cells loop from START, until it reaches END
b) A way to change the '0' (zeroes) in between the cells containing "START" and "END", so I can use conditional formatting to colour those cells.

Any help, tips, etc will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will highlight Start and END inclusively.

```
Sub colorMe()
    Dim lcell As Range
    Dim start_end As Boolean
    For Each lcell In Sheet1.Range("$A$2", "$S$7")
         If UCASE(Trim(lcell.Value)) = "START" Then
              start_end = True
         End If
         If start_end Then
             'Change 0 to something
             lcell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 102)
         Else
             lcell.Interior.Color = xlNone
         End If
         If  UCASE(Trim(lcell.Value)) = "END" Then
              start_end = False
         End If
   Next lcell
End Sub
```

This will highlight just values between Start and END

```
 Sub colorMe()
    Dim lcell As Range
    Dim start_end As Boolean
    For Each lcell In Sheet1.Range("$A$2", "$S$7")
         If  UCASE(Trim(lcell.Value)) = "END" Then
              start_end = False
         End If
         If start_end Then
             'Change 0 to something
             lcell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 102)
         Else
             lcell.Interior.Color = xlNone
         End If
         If  UCASE(Trim(lcell.Value)) = "START" Then
              start_end = True
         End If
   Next lcell
End Sub
```

Not sure what you want to Change the zeros to but just include the change inside the if. Also you will want to change the Range to fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

I have LibreOffice handy, but I think the conditional formatting behaves the same way as Excel.  Here's what's works with your example in LibreOffice:

```
=AND(NOT(COUNTIF(B1:$S$1,"START")>0),COUNTIF(A1:$S$1,"END")>0)
```

This assumes your values start in A1 and continue through S1 (for line 1) and that you apply the conditional formatting one line at a time (i.e., highlight the first row of values and apply, then highlight the 2nd row and apply, etc. for each of 6 rows).